# Can i take average of probability (p_1) value between two regression models?

Tags: regression, logistic, ensemble-learning

I have build two logistic regression models and I want to see I can ensemble (take average) of both models and see if performance improves?

P_1(model 1) + P_1 (model 2)/ 2= average P_1

Both models have same dependent variable, but different predictors.

Please help.

Comment: No one's going to call the police on you, but one might wonder why this is better than just building one model. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I understand. I can build one model including everything. I am new to statistics and I am building logistic regression model. I build one model using only Rx related variables, one model with medical related variables and one with only demographics. I was just trying to see if this approach is justifiable...

Comment: Because the dependent variable is the same for both models, it is possible to do this - however, the contribution from each model will be exaclty 1/2 of the total. If you can directly fit a scaling factor as in "total = (scale * model_1) + ((1-scale) * model_2" you may find a better mixture.